# How Can I know my Listbox is completely populated and displayed on page in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, progress-bar, populate

How Can I know when the Listbox is completely populated and is displayed to user in WP7. This is because it takes typically 1 to 2 seconds for listbox text to be displayed depending upon data,untill than  I need to display a progressbar to user instead of blank screen.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you want, but you can always monitor the [LayoutUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layoutupdated%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event: it changes everytime the ListBox visible content changes!

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is use a custom action (`Action<T>`) that is fired whenever the loading is done in the backend. I am assuming that you have a method that performs the loading, so pass that action as a parameter - whenever it is triggered, it means the method is done with data processing.